# SVG <view> bug in macOS Safari

Tags: css, svg, safari

I'm trying to create an SVG sprite that can be used both as bg and as inline svg via .

The following SVG mostly works:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1">
  <!-- symbols: used for inline SVGs via <use> -->
  <symbol id="tsg-en-logo" viewBox="0 0 100 11.1">
    <path fill="#0CA8D0" d="M0,2h1..."/>
  </symbol>
  <symbol id="chevron-down" viewBox="0 0 200 123.9">
    <g fill="#0CA8D0">
      <path d="M49..."/>
    </g>
  </symbol>
  <!-- views: used for bg images -->
  <view xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" id="tsg-en-logo-bg" width="100" height="11.1" viewBox="0 0 100 11.1"/>
  <view xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" id="chevron-down-bg" width="200" height="123.9" viewBox="0 12 200 123.9"/>
  <!-- uses: shown when acceses directly on the browser -->
  <use xlink:href="#tsg-en-logo" x="0" y="0" width="100" height="11.1" id="u-tsg-en-logo"></use>
  <use xlink:href="#chevron-down" x="0" y="12" width="200" height="123.9" id="u-chevron-down"></use>
</svg>
```

The problem is that when used as a BG, macOS Safari looses the proportions.

See full SVG here: https://cdn.rawgit.com/42pe/7a3a0193d3a142e7d93601340e6ee8fc/raw/81a7b0598b7179bdc071bba87569d53e2a7651e7/test.svg

And working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/42pe/Lragjqef/1/

Any idea why or how to fix? This works fine on Chrome, Firefox, IE11 and Edge!

Comment: view elements don't support width and height attributes. I doubt that's your problem though.

Comment: @RobertLongson correct on both. The problem is that the viewBox (and apparently any other attribute of a view) gets completely ignored by Ssafari. I'm trying them all, changing values and it displays the same every time.